# SQL - How to solve this queries that require the term 'ONLY'?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
customer(Id, Name, Address, PhoneNumber);
station (Id, City, Country, Location)
# e.g.: (123, ”London”, ”UK”, ”Stansted Airport”);
car(Id, Reg, Type, Milage);
contract(CustId, StationId, CarId);
```

Query1: Select all customers (names and contact number) who rented only BMW.

My Query:

```
SELECT Name, PhoneNumber 
FROM Car, Customer, Station, Contract 
WHERE customer.Id = CustId AND station.Id = StationId AND Car.Id = CarId AND Type = "BMW" 
GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(Distinct Type) = 1;
```

Query2: All customers who rented BMW and Aud

Comment: What is the purpose of GROUP BY?

Comment: SELECT Name, PhoneNumber.... GROUP BY Name is invalid SQL read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/... and don't use old JOIN syntax..

Answer (score 2):

You can first find the customer id who have rented only BMW using the `HAVING` clause and then join it with the customer table to get the relevant details for those customer ids.

Try this:

```
select c.name,
    c.phonenumber
from customer c
join (
    select c1.custId
    from Contract c1
    join Car c2 on c1.carId = c2.id
    group by c1.custId
    having count(distinct c2.Type) = 1
        and sum(c2.type = 'BMW') > 0
    ) t on c.id = t.custId;
```

Here:

- `count(distinct c2.Type) = 1` means there is only one type of car for the customer id.
- `sum(c2.type = 'BMW') > 0` means at least one car of type 'BMW' for the customer id

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the "then" and "end" keywords

Comment: I kind of understood it but I'm trying to interpret in a way which I can do it, so I built another query.

Comment: SELECT Name, PhoneNumber FROM Customer, Contract, Car WHERE Customer.Id NOT IN (SELECT CustId FROM Contract, Car, Customer WHERE Car.Id = CarId AND Customer.Id = CustId AND Type = "BMW") ;

Comment: @aSoulja - There are many things wrong - Starting with CROSS JOINS.

Comment: @aSoulja - Yes. See my answer.